# How to identify and kill git listening services here?

Tags: git, netstat, sysvinit

I am studying my listening services, and I am thinking how identify the type of `git` listening services so I can kill `git` the right one in the right situation and/or both. 
The services are needed for `git push` and `git pull` or `git clone [repos]`, working also for a git server (DopeGhoti). 
Code where I do not understand what each listening service is doing

```
masi@masi:~$ netstat -lt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 *:git                   *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:git                [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

Doing `netstat -plnt` but how to determine which belongs to Git A or B service

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5348          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:17991         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24698/rsession  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9418            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:34893           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9999            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::9418                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::9999                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::33875                :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5432                :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

OS: Debian 8.7
Git: 2.1.4

Comment: Downvoter! Please, leave a feedback. - Iterating for clarity is not a caveat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"So many of them?"  It's using precisely one, albeit on both the IPv4 and IPv6 interfaces.

Any service needs to be listening (or have a service aggregator such as `xinetd` listen by proxy) to *some* port or socket in order for incoming connections to be accepted.

In `/etc/services`, you can see git's port, 9418:

```
git             9418/tcp                        # Git Version Control System
```

Comment: For remote users to `git push` their code to, `git pull` code from, or `git clone` repositories from (et cetera); keep in mind that a git _server_ is distinct from a git _repository_.

Comment: Use `netstat -plnt` which will give you a numeric port as well as identify the listening process.

Comment: `git` is defined in `/etc/services` as running its service on TCP port 9418.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 `/etc/services` is just a mapping between standard service names and numbers.  It gives no information about what services are actually in use--there is no point in "commenting out" lines in `/etc/services`